# MySQL connect and Query in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I using these codes in my Model file, but I think it's wrong to use these mysql connects and queries in cakePHP, how I get it work, when I don't use this code?

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'User', 'pass');
mysql_select_db("database");

mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is my model file:

```
<?php   
     mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
     mysql_select_db("database");


    //$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE kontaktids"; //empty the table of its current records
    //mysql_query($deleterecords);

class Kontaktid extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
    var $name = 'Kontaktid';


    function import($filename) {
        // to avoid having to tweak the contents of
        // $data you should use your db field name as the heading name
        // eg: Post.id, Post.title, Post.description
        // set the filename to read CSV from
        $filename = TMP . 'uploads' . DS . 'Kontaktid' . DS . $filename;

        // open the file
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

        // read the 1st row as headings
        $header = fgetcsv($handle);

        // read each data row in the file

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $import="INSERT into kontaktids(id,Eesnimi,Perenimi,Maakond,Linn,Tanav,Maja,Telefon,lisanumbrid) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')";

            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }
         print "Import done";
        // close the file
        fclose($handle);

    }

}
```

Its working well, but I think its wrong to use these mysql queries

I tried something like this, but I dont get it work

```
$this->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

Thank you for helping !

**Solution**

Remove

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'User', 'pass');
mysql_select_db("database");

mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
```

And add these lines

```
$this->query ("INSERT into kontaktids(id,Eesnimi,Perenimi,Maakond,Linn,Tanav,Maja,Telefon,lisanumbrid) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')");
$this->query;
```

Comment: Why are you using CakePHP if you're not using any of its conventions?  Try reading through the tutorials in the CakePHP book.

Comment: Im learning cakePHP, and I dont know how to do these queries like cakePHP.

Comment: Right - and that's what the tutorials are for.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for some days, but without result. If I try something like this `$this->Kontaktid->query` then I get an error, and I dont know what to do next. I've tried a many solutions, but I dont get it work.

Comment: What you DO is go through the tutorials to LEARN a framework prior to just trying to jam random code into it.

Answer (score 1):

you can go app->config->database.php

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'database',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

}

after the you can execute this query`

```
$this->YourmodelName->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66398/discussion-on-answer-by-vikram-sharma-mysql-connect-and-query-in-cakephp).